# getElementsByClassName not returning length

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I want to get the `length` of the returned class names

There are a series of buttons that I want to add event listeners to and they all share the same class name.

`removeButton = document.getElementsByClassName("removeButton");`

When I do `removeButton.length` I always get `0` but if I do:

`console.log(removeButton)` I can see the list of items there.

I need the length so I can iterate through a `for-loop` and assign the event listeners.

What seems to be the problem?

**Solution**
Check that the elements exist before trying to gather them with getElementsByClassName

Comment: is the javascript being executed after the whole document loads? maybe you are trying to access elements that don't exist yet

Comment: Can you add the code that is surrounding `removeButton = document.getElementsByClassName("removeButton");`

Comment: The code itself works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/sRK8V/

Comment: @KaeruCT : that was the problem... the elements didn't exist yet.  Thanks

Comment: Instead of posting the solution in the question, you should either ask @KaeruCT to post an answer and accept it, or post and accept an answer of your own (that way the question doesn't show up as unanswered)

Comment: @KaeruCT : post the answer so i can give you the green check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be sure the elements exist if your JavaScript code depends on them.

One way of achieving this by putting the `<script>` tag at the end of the body like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // code here
</script>
</body>
```

You can also put all your code in a function for the `window.onload` event or use a library that provides this functionality, such as `jQuery`.

Comment: **NO!** You *never* put script elements in the body! You should be running functions called by `window.onload = function() {/*function calls here*/}` and use the `defer="defer"` attribute/value on all your script elements in the `head` element of the page.

Answer (score 1):

As OP stated,

> Check that the elements exist before trying to gather them with
>   getElementsByClassName.